# Windows 7 StoredCredentials Can't get password to show

Tags: powershell

In using the Get-StoredCredentials Powershell module, I cannot get the password to show for an entry where I used *runas* with *-savecred*.

This is my command:

```
Get-StoredCredential -AsCredentialObject -Type DomainPassword
```

This is the result from the target that I want to retrieve:

```
Flags          : 0
Type           : DomainPassword
TargetName     : Domain:target=SQL22Listener.dev.local
Comment        : SspiPfc
LastWritten    : 2/20/2019 12:15:40 PM
PaswordSize    : 0
Password       :
Persist        : Enterprise
AttributeCount : 0
Attributes     : 0
TargetAlias    :
UserName       : EPS\N46184A
```

Powershell Version:

```
Major  Minor  Build  Revision
-----  -----  -----  --------
5      1      14409  1012
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*That's the point?*

The credential object shouldn't return a password. If its a null password it should return as a blank value, otherwise it should return a `System.Security.SecureString`.

See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.pscredential.password

If you want to see if it is passing the `System.Security.SecureString` you can pipe the output and call the property `$_.password`. It should just return the string `System.Security.SecureString` which will contain just the property `length`.